# SQLite VS Firebase vs Local storage Especially for Images and add some data along with it ?For storing images along with some data in a Android app

Tags: java, android, sqlite, firebase

What would be suggested to store images along with other data?

My Android Mobile app takes the image and converts into scanned document(black and white) using an SDK. We can format into .tiff .png or .jpeg. but tiff has good quality.!! Along with this scanned document image we also have to save barcode!!

Later these images are used to upload them into an JSON API. api will convert image into bytes and stores into the cloud
As we upload into the api we are supposed to delete the images. As we reach some count say 50 images we are planning to delete images because it makes the app heavy.

I'm confused which storing method i have to use for storing images along with some data. Help is really appreciated. The Format I want to store is given below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PH3F.png)

Comment: use firebase for this.

Comment: @HemantParmar how can I store the extra information along with the image in fire base? . Is it possible?